# Using AppleScript and iMacros Browser in Python to create .app an/or .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, applescript, imacros

I've managed to take my everyday tasks at work and script them with iMacros (FireFox Extension) and AppleScript.(I basically do data entry style work). I make the macro in firefox and then bookmark it. I then write a simple applescript to open the bookmark in firefox and save it as an .app. Next time I need to do it it's all set up and done. I've started learning Python (I'm VERRRY new to it but was told it was the most similar to applescript and was one of the easiest to learn)

My boss saw what I had done and asked if i could make it work with windows. I'm mainly a Mac person but I have a decent understanding of windows.

Questions:

1. With Python can I take the iMacro script created when I record my actions and skip the use of iMacro? (i.e., Have Python do all the work/actions?)
2. If so: Is it possible to make this Python script into a .exe and/or .app file so other people can use it without the iMacros extension or the bookmark? (Most of my office is windows.)

Applescript

```
tell application "Firefox"
  open location "http://internalwebpage.com" 
  open location "imacros://run/?m=LogIn.iim" 
  delay 10 
  open location "imacros://run/?m=ExecuteList1.iim"
end tell
```

iMacros

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://internalwebpage.com/index.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:login ATTR=NAME:submitForm&&VALUE:LOGIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Selenium?
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/
Automates browsers, cross-platform, support for many languages, records and outputs code ... that's what I would look at.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. My desk is bloody and broken from banging my head on it. lol. Thanks again. I'll report back if this works.